# How to set the condition is null in Yii2 model search?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I want to set the condition which shows all vehicles where the `title_recieved` is `null`.

```
 ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'tr.title_recieved', null])
 ->andFilterWhere(['is', 'tr.title_recieved', null])
 ->andFilterWhere(['is', [ 'tr.title_recieved', null]])
```

I've tried all the available options, the is `null` condition works in `andWhere`, but not in `andFilterWhere`.

Comment: I guess according to [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryTrait.php#L190), it will not work.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere()-detail

Comment: @InsaneSkull what do then? I want to filter null value. how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try With This :

```
 ->andFilterWhere('tr.title_recieved is NULL');
```

Comment: This give me error : Argument 1 passed to yii\db\Query::andFilterWhere() must be of the type array, string given,

Answer (score 6):

Use andWhere on query liek this.

```
->andWhere(['tr.title_recieved' => null]);
```

Comment: yes this work fine but i need ->andFilterWhere(['tr.title_recieved' => null]);

Comment: ->andFilterWhere(['tr.title_recieved' => null]) this one is not working

Answer (score 1):

**As per yii2 doc 
andFilterWhere() Adds an additional WHERE condition to the existing one but ignores empty operands.

The new condition and the existing one will be joined using the 'AND' operator.

This method is similar to andWhere(). The main difference is that this method will remove empty query operands. As a result, this method is best suited for building query conditions based on filter values entered by users. 
From doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere()-detail **

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['IS', 'tr.title_recieved', new \yii\db\Expression('NULL')]);
```